# mod rewrite - set and get env variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I set env variables in a distributor htaccess file this way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [QSA,L,E=DOMAIN:%1,E=URI:$1]
```

After that apache start to process another htaccess file in the %1 subfolder.

How can I read the ENV:DOMAIN and ENV:URI variables in that htaccess?

I tried with

```
%{ENV:DOMAIN}
%{ENV:URI}
```

but those variables are empty...

Comment: Try using `%{ENV:REDIRECT_DOMAIN}` instead

Comment: Please send as an answer, btw. it works, thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `%{ENV:REDIRECT_DOMAIN}` instead. Apache adds the REDIRECT_ prefix before every environment variable, after rewriting.